# how to change opening a new window method

Tags: html, css, window

I have the code below in a webpage and it's job is: when the mouse just goes over the image, a new window shows up and when the mouse goes out, it disapears. All it does is ok but i just want it to shows up when i CLICK on the image and it disapears when i CLICK on outside of the new window.  Check it out.Help is needed

The code in header:

```
<style type="text/css">
a.imPop {
position:relative;
z-index:0;
}  
a.imPop:hover {
display:inline;
z-index:auto;
} 
a.imPop span {  
display:none;  
}
a.imPop:hover span {
display:inline;
position:left;
top:1em;
left:1em;
width:128px;
height:128px;
}

</style>
```

The code in body:

```
<a class="imPop" title="" style="color:#0000FF" font:large""> 
 <img src="images/1.gif" alt="" /><span>

<img src="images/2.jpg alt="" />


        </span> </a>
```

Comment: Put us up a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/
You are going to have to use javascript  of some type to get at the clicks from what i know you can't get click events with Css

Comment: You could use :active, but that will only work while the mouse is held. I'd recommend some js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this will do it in jquery if you have it on page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //this tracks the click on the class
    $('.imPop').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
              //this shows your span
        $('.imPop span').show();
    });
       //now this is flaky because you are looking for a click on the body tag of the   html it would be better to look for your page wrapper div and track clicks on that outside of the box
    $('body').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
           //this hide's the one you just showed!
        $('.imPop span').hide();
    });
});
```

Place this just before the closing  tag:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.imPop').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        $('.imPop span').show();
    });
    $('body').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        $('.imPop span').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

try this one:

```
        <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.imPop').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        $(this).children('span').show().addClass('showed');
    });
  $('body').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.showed').hide().removeClass('showed');
  });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't know anything about jquery. If this is the only way i need to give this code to someone expert to enter it to the page

Comment: send us the url of the page, and someone here will tell you where to put it

Comment: try the one below and remove the a.imPop:hover {} from the css to make sure it's the clikc doing it`

Comment: I completely removed that css and it worked. But doesn't hide when i click on the body.I added the code below after (span) show but still nothing:    $('body').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
$(this).children('span').hide();

Comment: Still nothing!! The new code works same. It shows up but doesn't hide. Really why doesn't hide?!

Comment: becuase your tracking clicks on the body give me a min to take a look.. also a upvote on the answer since nobody else bothered to answer you would be nice!

Comment: put it back on the page and I'll take a look

Comment: vimes i replaced all the code with a new code. It solved the problem. Now the site is working properly. Yes i wondered how no one else knew how to fix this! I appreciate your knowledge and thank you so much for the time. Take a look at the site if you too see it.

Comment: Looks good :D glad to have helped. I suspect it's not that no one else knew how to fix it but that noone else took the time to look at it! can you accept the answer if it works please(just click the tick below the vote up down arrow)